# Corsair iCue -- Programming Mouse Button to Launch .BAT file which changes Default Audio Device in Windows 7 -- Does Not Launch

Tags: windows-7, audio, batch, mouse

I'm running Windows 7 x64 and have recently installed a [Corsair Scimitar Pro mouse](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Color/scimitar-pro-config/p/CH-9304111-NA) and [iCue 3.5.111](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/icue) to drive the special features of the mouse, like programmable side-buttons.

I'm trying to map to mouse button #8 the function of switching my default audio device in the Windows Sound Control Panel by using a third-party application, [nircmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). The nircmd executable (nircmd.exe) is referenced in a Batch file, 'audioswitch.bat' which is supposed to be launched from iCue.

[image]

However, the Batch file never launches when I press the button on the mouse, even though I've selected the Batch file to be launched in iCue:

[image]

It might be worth pointing out that I have no problem executing .exe files directly via iCue. But launching Batch files seems to not work. I'm keen to know if anyone has any insight on how I might solve this problem. I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that iCue seems to launch the batch file from the location of iCue.exe, so it can't find nircmd even if the batch file it's running is in the same directory as nircmd.exe. To fix this, you can either add nircmd to your system PATH variable, or change your batch file to something like this:

```
"C:\pathtoexecutable\nircmd" setdefaultsounddevice "MoBo" 1
"C:\pathtoexecutable\nircmd" setdefaultsounddevice "MoBo" 2
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This immediately fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c “c:\thepathto\your.bat”
```

Double check that’s where cmd.exe is saved. It might be `c:\windows`

Should be easy to figure out. Double check the flag too. But what you are saying is: using the command processor that reads bats, run this bat file and close when complete (/c) /k means keep. But you can run from command line `cmd.exe /?` and get reminded of the flags.

That should solve it because it’s running a native executable which then runs the script. The bat only has meaning because you use the Windows shell to open it normally. E. g. Clicking on it. Inside the program may operate independently of the shell, many do, and that’s beyond the scope here.

Comment: On a side note. Command and bat are basically deprecated (discontinued) by windows and only there for historical reasons. Learning power shell or windows script -which is the language JavaScript or VBScript will dramatically increase the “power” you have to control anything you can think of. To be fair- windows script is now deprecated as well, and PowerShell has emerged as the defacto windows “command line”. It is difficult to learn- at least I think so. I’m trying now.

Comment: I set iCue to run c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "c:\users\rudy\downloads\nircmd-x64\audioswitch.bat", but it still doesn't seem to launch. I confirmed that cmd.exe is in the system32 directory.